# Print from tab to a printer connected through LAN to same network

Tags: android, android-networking, android-print-framework

I have a printer connected through LAN to the same network that of an android tab. The printing should be a specific format with images and tables. I don't want any dialogs shown during the printing process. The printing process should be automatic.

```
try {


                Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.10.22", 9100);
                PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                oStream.println("HI,test from Android Device");
                oStream.println("\n\n\n");
                oStream.println("Printing works!!!");
                oStream.println("\n\n\n");
                oStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();


            }
```

I tried the above code but I can't change the font size or print images

Comment: By `tab`, do you mean `tablet`? If so, why is it be relevant that your device is a tablet and not a phone?

Comment: @Fantômas I'm developing an app for an android tablet which requires printing through LAN connected printer without user interaction